# Understanding Enqueue in Princeton's Queue Tutorial

Tags: java, reference

Why is last.next being assigned to x, if last is going to become x? I don't see how assigning x to last.next affects anything.
Here's the full context of the queue: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/43stack/Queue.java.html

```
public void enqueue(Item item) {
    Node x = new Node();
    x.item = item;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        first = x;
        last = x;
    }
    else {
        last.next = x;
        last = x;
    }
    N++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `last.next = x;` performs the actual addition of the node to the end of the linked list.

```
 (rest) -> (node)         ===>     (rest) -> (node) -> (x)
             ^                                 ^
             |                                 |
           last                               last
```

However, now the `last` reference is out of date; it needs to be updated to refer to the last item that we just added, which `last = x;` does.

```
(rest) -> (node) -> (x)   ===>     (rest) -> (node) -> (x) 
           ^                                            ^
           |                                            |
          last                                         last
```

Comment: I guess I don't know how Java references work. Thanks for this!